# How to get domain name by IP Address and port in native NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

Which method is closest to **desiredMethod** in below code?

```js
const dns = require("dns");

const IP_ADDRESS = "XX.XX.XXX.XXX"; // Any valid IP address
const PORT = 8080;

dns.deiredMethod(`${IP_ADDRESS}:${PORT}`, (error, domain) => {
   console.log(domain); // example output: "example.com"
})
```

Comment: Do you mean a reverse lookup? https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dnsreverseip-callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure if I understand correct what you try to achieve. But the native `dns` module of an Node.js installation allows to resolve hostnames by IP address and port using `dns.lookupService(address, port, callback)`. Please see [Node.js DNS](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dnslookupserviceaddress-port-callback) for details.

```
const dns = require("dns");

dns.lookupService('172.217.18.110', 22, (err, hostname, service) => {
    console.log(hostname, service);
});
```